# How is this given impulse response of infinite duration? Isn't it just from -π to +π?

Tags: filters, filter-design, digital-filters, fourier, fourier-series

How is hd(n) infinite duration when it is from  -π to +π. Book says as it is infinite duration, we in the next step take-:

h[n]=hd[n] from n=-(N-1)/2 to (N-1)/2 and 0 otherwise.

I can't see how this hd[n] is infinite. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The integral (by the way, an inverse Fourier transform of sorts) doesn't "remove" the $n$ from the exponent, so this remains something that still contains the complex exponential $e^{j\omega n}$ – and that has infinite extension along the $n$ axis.

Comment: I see. the integral we get is j*sin(nπ)/π. So you mean n value ranges from -∞ to +∞. I forgot what this n is about? What is the meaning of n here? Is it number of samples?

Comment: as you can see in your formula, it's the "running" variable. You can call it "time", if that fits in your case, makes sense since you're asking about "duration". You seem to be a bit confused in general what is which your material's framework – I can't help you with that, as I don't have the same material. The only way to help yourself here is go back and read the notation very carefully as it's introduced.

Comment: Thanks you cleared my confusion. I will understand n meaning later.

Comment: I'll urge you to understand it **now**. You're basing your learning on looking at things without understanding otherwise.